# Well-ordering on closed subsets of R

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I don't know how to approach the proof of the following statement:

If $A$ is a family of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ well-ordered with respect to inclusion, then $A$ is countable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Here's a good place to start: can you think of an example of a family $A$ which *is* well-ordered with respect to inclusion?  (You know in advance that your family $A$ will have to be countable).

Comment: For example we could consider the family A={{1},{1,2},{1,2,3},...}. Then every set {1,...n} is closed and it is well-ordered with respect to inclusion. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, good example.  How about one where your closed subsets are not finite sets, but intervals instead?

Comment: We can take family of closed intervals [-n,n] for natural n.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is flawed - Maybe all rationals are in all open sets. Here's a different approach. Let $\{B_n : n < \omega\}$ list all rational intervals. Associate to each closed set $A$ the set $X_A = \{n < \omega : A \cap B_n = \phi\}$. Now check.

Comment: +1. To fill in a bit: the point is that the map $A\mapsto X_A$ is injective, and $A\subseteq B$ implies $X_A\supseteq X_B$. So if we had an $\omega_1$-length increasing chain of closed sets, that would yield an $\omega_1$-length *decreasing* sequence of sets of natural numbers. But since there are only countably many naturals, this can't happen. (This is a much better answer than mine; I've kept mine around, though, since the argument style is a very useful one.)

Comment: This answer should be accepted, if only for the hilarity of the ensuing paradoxical first sentence.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. I see 3 answers,none accepted (yet). Good paradoxical thinking.:)

Comment: Thank you. Oh, now I can't accept answers (although there are very nice solutions and generalization)! :)

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Suppose towards a contradiction that I have a family of closed sets $A_\eta$ for $\eta<\omega_1$, with $\eta<\theta$ implies $A_\eta\subsetneq A_\theta$.

- Show that for each *successor ordinal* $\eta$, there is some $x\in A_\eta$ which is not a limit of any sequence of points from $\bigcup_{\alpha<\eta}A_\alpha$. *This is where we use that the $A_\eta$s are closed.*
- Do you see how to use this fact to construct an uncountable set of reals which is discrete? Do you see why that's a problem?

---

More detail: Suppose $\{A_\theta: \theta\in\omega_1\}$ is an increasing sequence of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. We'll build by induction an uncountable discrete set of reals, $D$, which can't exist. At stage $\alpha$, we define a real $x_\alpha$ and a positive real $\epsilon_\alpha$, as follows: we let $x_\alpha$ be some element of $\bigcup A_\theta$ such that $$d(x_\alpha, x_\beta)<\epsilon_\beta$$ for all $\beta<\alpha$ and $x_\alpha$ is **not** an accumulation point of $\{x_\beta: \beta<\alpha\}$, and $\epsilon_\alpha$ be some positive real such that the set $$\{y\in \bigcup A_\theta: d(y, x_\alpha)>\epsilon_\alpha\}$$ is uncountable.

You can show that such $x_\alpha$ and $\epsilon_\alpha$ can always be picked. But then it's clear that the set $\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ is discrete.

Comment: If I understood correctly, for every $A_\theta$ we choose the successor (there can be almost one element which doesn't have it), for instance starting from the smallest element. There is $x\in A_\eta$ which is not in $A_\theta$ for $\theta<\eta$. If it was a limit of any sequence in $A_\theta$, $A_\theta$ wouldn't be closed, which is contradiction. So taking such points for every $A_\theta\in A$ (expect the biggest element) we have uncountable set of reals which should be discrete. I haven't seen yet why it's discrete.

Comment: @Cofibration It's not quite that easy, sadly. You can rule out a sequence increasing to $x_\eta$ consisting of $x_\delta$s for $\delta<\eta$, but you can't immediately rule out a sequence consisting of points from *later* sets. So the construction needs to be a bit more careful - you need to argue that there's a way to pick points so that you avoid all possible converging sequences. But this is a standard trick in transfinite induction arguments: at a given stage, you'll have picked countably many points, and so you have countably many "requirements" for future stages . . .

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with transfinite induction arguments. I hope it will change soon.

Comment: Thank you for details about induction argument

Answer (score 2):

More generally, let $X$ be any hereditarily separable topological space. Assume for a contradiction that there is an uncountable family of closed subsets of $X$ which is well-ordered by inclusion. Then there is an uncountable family of closed sets of order type $\omega_1,$ i.e., there are closed sets $A_\alpha(\alpha\lt\omega_1)$ such that $A_\beta\subsetneq A_\alpha$ for $\beta\lt\alpha\lt\omega_1.$ Let $A=\bigcup_{\alpha\lt\omega_1}A_\alpha,$ and let $S$ be a countable dense subset of $A.$ Choose $\beta\lt\omega_1$ so that $S\subseteq A_\beta.$ Then $A_{\beta+1}\subseteq A\subseteq\bar S\subseteq\overline{A_\beta}=A_\beta$ contradicting $A_\beta\subsetneq A_{\beta+1}.$

Comment: Thank you for your solution- generalization.